# ls and sort by number for human

Tags: ls, sort

I create catalogs
`mkdir site_{1..44}`. I want to sort them

```
site_1
site_2
site_3
site_4
...
site_44
```

I execute the command
`ls | sort -h` and I have

```
site_1
site_10
site_11
site_12
site_13
site_14
site_15
site_16
site_17
site_18
site_19
site_2
site_20
site_21
site_22
site_23
site_24
site_25
site_26
site_27
site_28
site_29
site_3
site_30
site_31
site_32
site_33
site_34
site_35
site_36
site_37
site_38
site_39
site_4
site_40
site_41
site_42
site_43
site_44
site_5
site_6
site_7
site_8
site_9
```

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: With GNU `sort`, `-h` compares things like `1G` with `100M` etc. whereas what I think you want is `-V`.  To get a list of the directories that you just created, the easiest would be to use the same brace expansion though: `printf '%s\n' site_{1..44}`.  I'm uncertain why you feel you need to [parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985), so I'm not turning this into an answer. See also `ls -v` on a GNU system.

Answer (score 8):

With GNU `ls`:

```
ls -1 -v
```

```
ls --format=single-column --sort=version
```

With GNU `sort` (and assuming file names don't contain newline characters):

```
ls | sort -V
```

```
ls | sort --version-sort
```

With `zsh`, you can also get globs to sort numerically with the `n` glob qualifier:

```
print -rC1 -- *(Nn)
```

<sup>(here also using the `N`ullglob qualifier so it prints nothing instead of giving an error if there's no matching file (no non-hidden files with `*` as the pattern)).</sup>

If passing to `ls`, you'd need to tell `ls` to disable its own sorting (`-U` / `--sort=none` with GNU `ls`):

```
ls -ldU -- *(n)
```

<sup>(here, not using `N` because if not passed any argument, `ls` will list `.` instead of listing nothing).</sup>

You can also make it the default there with `set -o numericglobsort`.

But maybe better here would be to use 0-padding in your file names so they sort the same numerically and lexically:

```
mkdir site_{01..44}    # zsh, bash, yash -o braceexpand
mkdir site_{1..44%02d} # ksh93
```

GNU's `sort -h` itself it to sort *human readable sizes* as displayed by `du -h` or `ls -sh` for instance where `123456789` for instance is represented as `118M`, so it's of no use here.

In your case as those `site_1`... do not start with what looks like a *human readable size*, they are all considered as 0 and sort the same. You do however get a lexical sort thanks to the last-resort comparison which breaks ties by comparing full lines lexically.

Even if your directories were named `site_314`, `site_1.1K`, `site_0.9M` and you wanted to sort them based on the size found after the `_`, you'd need to tell `sort` where the *human readable size* is as in `sort -t_ -k1,1 -k2h` to sort first on the part before the first `_` lexically, and then on the part after the `_`, interpreting it as a *human readable size* with the `h` flag to the `k`ey  specification.